# If $x:V\rightarrow V$ is diagonalizable then $\text{adj}(x):g\ell(V)\rightarrow g\ell(V)$ is too.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$. Let $g\ell(V)$ be the set of linear maps from $V$ to itself with the Lie bracket $[x,y]=x\circ y-y\circ x$. We will write $xy:=x\circ y$. For each $x\in g\ell(V)$ define $\text{adj}(x):g\ell(V)\rightarrow g\ell(V)$ by $(\text{adj}(x))(y)=[x,y]$. We want to show that if $x$ is diagonalizable, then $\text{adj}(x)$ is too.

For me $x$ being diagonalizable means there is a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ and $b,d\in g\ell(V)$ with $b$ invertible such that $M_{\mathcal{B}}(d)$ is a diagonal matrix and $x=b^{-1}db$. Here $M_{\mathcal{B}}(a)$ is the matrix in $F^{n\times n}$ (the space of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$ and $n=\dim(V)$) of $a\in g\ell(V)$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$.

I did a quick computation and saw that for all $y\in g\ell(V)$, we have $$\text{adj}(x)(y)=\text{adj}(b^{-1}db)(y)=b^{-1}[d,byb^{-1}]b,$$
so if we define $C:g\ell(V)\rightarrow g\ell(V)$ by $C(y)=byb^{-1}$, then we see that $$\text{adj}(x)(y)=(C^{-1}\circ\text{adj}(d)\circ C)(y)$$ so that we have factored $\text{adj}(x)$ as $$\text{adj}(x)=C^{-1}\text{adj}(d)C.$$
Now, how do we go about finding a basis $\tilde{B}$ in $g\ell(V)$ such that $M_{\tilde{\mathcal{B}}}(\text{adj}(d))$ is diagonal? Once we can do this then we should be done.

Comment: Hint: you have a nice basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $V$. Can you use that to construct a nice basis for $g\ell(V)$?

Comment: It's definitely clear to me that I need to use $\mathcal{B}$ but you could maybe say more about how I would start the construction? I will need $n^2$ maps. My only thought is to use maps that send the $b_i\in \mathcal{B}$ to themselves and the rest of the basis elements to zero, but this only gives me $n$ maps and then I would need to complete the basis somehow.

Comment: Those are definitely good, we just need more. Here's a variation on your theme: what if allow maps that send $b_i$ to some other basis vector? That is, we look at maps $E_{ij} : V \to V$ that sends $b_k$ to zero if $k\neq j$, and it sends $b_j$ to $b_i$.

Comment: Then the $n$ vectors you picked out are just $E_{ii}$

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Then I just have to compute $\text{adj}(d)(E_{i,j})$ and expand it in terms of the $E_{ij}$. Thanks.

Comment: Another hint: It turns out that the eigenvalues of $ad(x)$ are the pairwise differences of the eigenvalues of $x$. This should come out of your computations almost for free.

Comment: If you want to check your work, this is proven in Humphrey's 'Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation theory' on page 18.